# Find term for one angle of two in a trig function

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In a right angled triangle, I know that $\tan (x) = \cfrac{4}{z}$ and that $\tan(x+y) = \cfrac{12}{z}$.

I need to find an equation which has only $\tan(y)$.

The answer is $\cfrac{12}{z} = \cfrac{\frac{4}{z} + \tan(y)}{1-\frac{4}{z}\tan(y)}$, but I have no clue how this was justified. I am currently taking high school calculus.

Comment: What do you want to describe with such an equation?

Comment: I'm trying to do the last question in this paper:

[link]http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/nqfdocs/ncea-resource/exams/2010/90635-exm-2010.pdf

the answer I stated above is not actually the final answer, but supposedly the next step after establishing the first two equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is justified using the [angle addition formula for tangents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities):

$$\tan{(\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{\tan{\alpha}+\tan{\beta}}{1-\tan{\alpha}\tan{\beta}}.$$

Substituting $\tan{\alpha}=\frac{4}{z}$ and $\tan{(\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{12}{z}$ in the identity above will give you the desired equation.

Comment: thanks a heap :) I haven't actually learnt this yet which is why I didn't make the connection, but that's sorted now. thanks.

Comment: @user2862492 Have you at least encountered the addition formulas for sine and cosine? If so, then you could actually use them to derive the addition formula for tangent relatively easily.